# Change the color of a row in table, html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a table using html and css. But my problem is that I want the table to have the rows in 2 colors, one orange and one white....I use javascript to fill the table. But  i cant change the color in the second case.. What sintax should i use to change th ecolor of  row when using Javascript, because it gives me an error...My code is below:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Account Type</th>
            <th>Minimun Required</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Compounded</th>

        </tr>
                <!--To fill the table with javascript-->
            <script >
                for (var j=0;j<col1.length;j++){
                    if (j%2==0) {
                        document.write("<tr><td>"  + col1[j] + " </td>");
                        document.write("<td>" + col2[j] + "</td>");
                        document.write("<td>" + col3[j] + "</td>");
                        document.write("<td>" + col4[j] + "</td></tr>");
                            }
                    else
                    { 
                document.write("<tr bgcolor="#d9531e"><td>"  + col1[j] + " </td>");
                                document.write("<td>" + col2[j] + "</td>");
                document.write("<td>" + col3[j] + "</td>");
                document.write("<td>" + col4[j] + "</td></tr1>");
                }}

            </script>

        </table>
```

and the error is at this line:

```
document.write("<tr bgcolor="#d9531e"><td>"  + col1[j] + " </td>");
```

Thank you!

Comment: The color coding in the blocks above shows the error! Also learn about thead and tbody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to nest double-quotes inside a double-quoted string literal. You need to either escape them as `\"`:

```
document.write("<tr bgcolor=\"#d9531e\"><td>"  + col1[j] + " </td>");
```

...or use single quotes:

```
document.write("<tr bgcolor='#d9531e'><td>"  + col1[j] + " </td>");
```

(Not that I recommend using `document.write()`.)

Note that it is generally considered best practice to set colours using CSS. You can add the following to your stylesheet:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #d9531e;
}
```

...and it will automatically do the every-second-row colour for you as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/rUK8a/

Comment: Thank a lot...I forgot that detail

Answer (score 0):

Well one problem is that you are using the same type of quotes -- you want to use different ones so don't terminate your string constant.  You can see in the syntax color the problem.

```
 document.write("<tr bgcolor='#d9531e'><td>"  + col1[j] + " </td>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you have un-escaped quotes inside of your write() function. Try this instead:

```
document.write("<tr bgcolor=\"#d9531e\"><td>"  + col1[j] + " </td>");
```

or use different quotes, like:

```
document.write("<tr bgcolor='#d9531e'><td>"  + col1[j] + " </td>");
```

or you can even get away with no quotes at all as long as there are no spaces. I don't recommend this method:

```
document.write("<tr bgcolor=#d9531e><td>"  + col1[j] + " </td>");
```

In general, since the only difference is the color of the row, I would encourage you to take columns 2-4 outside of the if-else statement so you don't need to write them twice.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline table tags to color a particular row. You must escape double quotes or need to use opposite quotes.

```
    document.write("<tr bgcolor=\"color code\"><td></td>...</tr>");  // use \ to escape double quote

or 

    document.write("<tr bgcolor='color code'><td></td>...</tr>");  // use ' inside the " .
```

Comment: Hhm, Got it. Edited my answer.forget escape those quotes..i OP